# How is it possible that there is visually no difference between 8-bit and 16-bit images?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am trying to test how much information will I lose if I convert (initially) 16-bit images that I've read from .dcm files using pydicom module, to 8-bit images. Here is visualization code that I am using:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def show_images(images, row_num=1, col_num=None):
  if not col_num:
    col_num = len(images)

  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12., 12.))  
  grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(row_num, col_num),axes_pad=0.1)
  
  for ax, im in zip(grid, images):
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.imshow(im, cmap="gray")

show_images([raw_image_8, agcwd_image_8, raw_image_16, agcwd_image_16], row_num=2, col_num=2)
```

And here is what I get as an output:

[image]

As you can see, visually no difference at all. Now is this due to the ImageGrid class, or some other in-built functionality that I am not aware of, or is there really no difference?

Note on how I've obtained images:

1. Read them from .dcm files using pydicom as 16-bit images
2. Wrote them back on disk as .png
3. Using cv2.imread("image_path") i've obtained 8-bit images (default OpenCV setting), and using cv2.imread("image_path", -1) I've obtained 16-bit images (-1 argument tells OpenCV to read image as is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do lose information when converting from 16-bit to 8-bit, it's just that the information lost does not show in your example.

If you crop just the left portion of the image where the grey is much fainter, convert vs not convert it to 8-bit, then re-adjust the contrast, you'll see that processed 8-bit image would have a less smooth gradient of grey compared to the 16-bit image. In my work with fluorescence microscopy images, I will therefore always adjust the contrast of the 16-bit image *before* converting it to 8-bit, so that the conversion will not produce a perceptible visual difference in quality

Comment: Would you please share technique you are using for adjustig the contrast? Is there a paper or?

Comment: I do it with ImageJ (https://fiji.sc), so I'm not sure whether this plugs into your workflow. There's a Brightness & Contrast tool in ImageJ with which you can adjust the contrast by selecting the range of pixel intensities (eg. 200 - 10000) that you want to consider as your new full range. This means you are considering intensities of 0-199 all as "min" and 10001-65535 all as "max". After this adjustment step, you convert to 8-bit, so that your range of interest (200-10000) is well spread out over 0-255.
If you had first converted to 8-bit, your intensity range of interest only spans ~0-40

Answer (score 2):

The website https://gregbenzphotography.com/photography-tips/8-vs-16-bit-depth-photoshop gives a good visual description of 1-bit to 14-bit gray scale.  The truth is, beyond 8-bits, the difference is really pretty subtle.

You also need to check how good your monitor is.  Your monitor may not support more than 8-bits per color channel.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that [the human eye can distinguish about 50 discrete shades of grey](https://www.olympus-lifescience.com/en/microscope-resource/primer/digitalimaging/concepts/dynamicrange) within the intensity range of a video monitor, i.e., you can not appreciate depths beyond 6-7 bits on your screen.